# Repeat statement for infinite times using loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to print like:

```
for(int i=0;i<should be infinite;i++)
{
    Data is Loading.
    sleep(100);
    Data is Loading..
    sleep(100);
    Data is Loading... 
    sleep(100);
}
```

below is  the  code  its not  working

```
package com.queen.a01_simple_request;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (; ; ) {
                try {
                    textView.setText("Downloading The File");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    textView.setText("Downloading The File.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    textView.setText("Downloading The File..");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    textView.setText("Downloading The File...");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Now, this should loop for infinite. The dots should change one after another forever. I dont want to set value like i<1000. I want to implement this.

Comment: if you want an infinit Loop then just make a `while(true)`

Comment: Will you please give  me an example on that?

Comment: Simply omit the guard condition: `for (int i = 0; /* nothing */; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 "parts" of the [basic for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) are optional:

```
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

So, whilst it looks strange, this is a valid for loop (that does nothing, forever):

```
for (;;);
```

In your case, just omit `Expression`:

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(;;){
    {
    try{
     Data is Loading.
     Thread.sleep(100);
     Data is Loading..
     Thread.sleep(100);
     Data is Loading... 
     Thread.sleep(100);
    }catch(Exception ignored){}
    }
```

**EDIT :**
if you are doing this on the main thread (UI Thread) it will freezes the application, you have to start the loop in the background like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
       for(;;){
            try{
             Data is Loading.
             Thread.sleep(100);
             Data is Loading..
             Thread.sleep(100);
             Data is Loading... 
             Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception ignored){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: youzking, its not working..
When i press the button, it is like freezing...

Comment: @AppleAppala well duh. You requested an infinite loop

Comment: @TimCastelijns yeh.. i posted the output above... its not working... Please take a look..

Comment: @AppleAppala if you use an infinite loop in the UI Thread it will freezes the application cause the loop will not let time to User Interface to refresh, you have to launch this on the background, I've edited the Answer retry

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
while(true){
   code...
}
```